# How to run Unicorn's makefile?

Tags: c, shell, emulation

So I'm trying to follow the Unicorn tutorial: https://www.unicorn-engine.org/docs/tutorial.html

I installed Unicorn using

```
pip3 install unicorn
```

In my `main.c` I got

```
#include <unicorn/unicorn.h>

// code to be emulated
#define X86_CODE32 "\x41\x4a" // INC ecx; DEC edx

// memory address where emulation starts
#define ADDRESS 0x1000000

int main(int argc, char ** argv, char ** envp) {
    uc_engine * uc;
    uc_err err;
    int r_ecx = 0x1234; // ECX register
    int r_edx = 0x7890; // EDX register

    printf("Emulate i386 code\n");

    // Initialize emulator in X86-32bit mode
    err = uc_open(UC_ARCH_X86, UC_MODE_32, & uc);
    if (err != UC_ERR_OK) {
        printf("Failed on uc_open() with error returned: %u\n", err);
        return -1;
    }

    // map 2MB memory for this emulation
    uc_mem_map(uc, ADDRESS, 2 * 1024 * 1024, UC_PROT_ALL);

    // write machine code to be emulated to memory
    if (uc_mem_write(uc, ADDRESS, X86_CODE32, sizeof(X86_CODE32) - 1)) {
        printf("Failed to write emulation code to memory, quit!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // initialize machine registers
    uc_reg_write(uc, UC_X86_REG_ECX, & r_ecx);
    uc_reg_write(uc, UC_X86_REG_EDX, & r_edx);

    // emulate code in infinite time & unlimited instructions
    err = uc_emu_start(uc, ADDRESS, ADDRESS + sizeof(X86_CODE32) - 1, 0, 0);
    if (err) {
        printf("Failed on uc_emu_start() with error returned %u: %s\n",
            err, uc_strerror(err));
    }

    // now print out some registers
    printf("Emulation done. Below is the CPU context\n");

    uc_reg_read(uc, UC_X86_REG_ECX, & r_ecx);
    uc_reg_read(uc, UC_X86_REG_EDX, & r_edx);
    printf(">>> ECX = 0x%x\n", r_ecx);
    printf(">>> EDX = 0x%x\n", r_edx);

    uc_close(uc);

    return 0;
}
```

In the `Makefile` I got:

```
LDFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0) -lpthread -lm -lunicorn

all: test
%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

But when I try to run `make` but I got these errors:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'test', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunicorn
fatal error: unicorn/unicorn.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Rename `main.c` to `test.c`

In your `Makefile`, the target `all` that is executed, when you issue the command `make`, depends on the target `test`. If the target `test` is not specified in your `Makefile`, `make` command will try to compile a source file in your current directory with the name `test.c`.

The compilation will occure based on:

```
%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Make will try to compile a file with the name `test.c` and store the compilation result in `test.o`

In your case, you named the source file `main.c`, it should be renamed to `test.c` so that the `make` command can find the file to fulfill the rules required to execute the `test` target.